# Slider Input Slected Ranges showing up as NULL

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to print the selected ranged for a slider input in R but it is showing up null.

here is my UI.r

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Test"),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("StikeRange", "Strike Range:",   min = 1, max = 10, value = c(4,6) )
 ),

 mainPanel(

   verbatimTextOutput("test")
 )
))
```

Here is my server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$test<-renderPrint({
    print( c(input$StrikeRange[1],input$StrikeRange[2]))
  })
```

})

It is currently printing NULL.

Any idea how to access the Ranges?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Test"),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("StrikeRange", "Strike Range:",   min = 1, max = 10, value = c(4,6) )
 ),
```

Not sure if that solves your problem, but you have a typo in the ui.R:
you wrote "StikeRange" without the **r**.